# ASM Debuggers that visualize the stack (beginner friendly)

Tags: disassembly, assembly, debuggers, stack, stack-variables

(Cross-posted from Stack Overflow)

Are there any debuggers that constantly show a visual of the stack and where everything is within it? For example, taking some random image:

[image]

I use `gdb` for most debugging/learning, and while it does show the registers, I have to do something like `x/8gx $rbp-32` everytime I want to see the stack -- and from that I usually figure out how I want the data to show.

Are there any debuggers that make this information friendlier and more visual? I am very, very new to asm and the visual does help when debugging the information. (I'm hoping some off-the-shelf product such as Hopper, IDA, x86db, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using *nix based systems since you mentioned `gdb`. If you just want to print the stack/registers when you hit a break point, you can use `command` to set up some print statements. See [here](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Break-Commands.html#Break-Commands).

Installing [pwndbg](https://github.com/pwndbg/pwndbg) makes it a lot less exhausting as it prints out the stack and registers every time you step, with  labels on the stack identifying `rbp` and `rsp`. Additionally there are tools like [GEF](https://github.com/hugsy/gef) and [PEDA](https://github.com/longld/peda) that are similar, but I don't have any firsthand experience with them.
[image: pwndbg]

Additionally, there are a few debuggers with GUIs, if that is what you are looking for:

- [ddd](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/): graphical front end for `gdb`, but you'll still see the stack as a list of values.
- [edb](https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger): similar to `ollydbg`, but for Linux.
- [gdbgui](https://github.com/cs01/gdbgui): browser based frontend for `gdb`.

Comment: thanks for all these tips. I'm currently using `gdbgui` but I have to use the print each time I want to see the stack!

Answer (score 1):

Borland's Turbo Debugger also has a text-window-based UI, with the stack in its own window and showing which values in which locations.  It doesn't tell you what those values represent, but at least it's always visible.